# Cannot install Charles SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

I'm trying to use charles SSL proxying on my Huawei Honor Bee phone. When I try to install the certificate from charlesproxy.com/getssl, I get an error toast saying, "Couldn't install because the certificate file couldn't be read". I've tried on different browsers, but no luck. How can I install the charles certificate? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I've just had this on a Fairphone 2. It didn't work from the browser, or from the download notification, randomly it did work from the downloads app though!

Comment: comment is the answer for me

Comment: Thanks for @deive 's comment. In my case it did not work when opened in the file explorer, but works when opened from the download notification.

Answer (score 32):

On your phone, Go to Settings > Security > Install from storage.
Locate your certificate file and install it.

Comment: This did not work for me. The file is greyed out in downloads. Edit: I was using Firefox and it did not work. I tried the link in Chrome and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to help menu and choose "export root certificate" then just send this file to the device.
An image to exemplify what I mean: https://tppr.me/ymh8W

Comment: Thank you,  brunoais.
Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For Mi4i, Go To Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy -> Install From Storage -> Install certificate which is present in your Downloads

To verify if it's installed Go to Trusted credentials -> Click on User tab -> Check if certificate exists or not.